# C++ разбиение define на части

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, препроцессор

Подскажите, как реализовать разбиение define на части.

Есть код:

```
#define F(t, n, v) t n = v;
```

Вызываю:

```
F(int, test, 1);
```

Ок.

Хочу заменить параметры дефайном:

```
#define T int, test2, 1
```

Вызываю:

```
F(T);
```

Не работает, по тому как результат приобретает вид:

```
int, test2, 1 = ;
```

То есть все переменные вставляются в первый параметр.

Как указать препроцессору, чтобы он развернул T как три параметра, а не один?

Comment: Но зачем?​​​​​​

Comment: В данном примере не за чем, но когда есть список переменных, которые нужно передать в кучу других макросов, подобный код обретает смысл и сильно упрощает написание кода.

Comment: Не получится у Вас это сделать, потому что MSVC неправильно обрабатывает макросы. Увы и ах, 2015 студия ничем не лучше. Так что либо отказывайтесь от такого решение, либо от студии.

Comment: Либо написать свой препроцессор. Чем и занимаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы написал свой препроцессор https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/tree/master/msvxcc . Реализовав дополнительное обозначение :: указывающее, что параметры необходимо развернуть.

```
#define A 1, 2, 3
#define B(a, b, ...) printf(a, __VA_ARGS__ );
    B("%d %d %d\r\n", 1, 2, 3);
    B("%d %d %d\r\n", ::A);
```

В примере две последние строчки будут идентичны, так как A подставится в виде его значения.

Comment: Свой, это всегда здорово. Как только будет время обязательно посмотрю.

Answer (score 3):

Может так?

```
// t.c
#define  F(t, n, v) t n = v;
F(int, test, 1);
#define T int, test2, 1
#define FFF(t, n, v)  t n = v;
#define FF(t) FFF(t)
FF(T);
```

Запустим препроцессор

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc -E t.c
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "t.c"

int test = 1;;



int test2 = 1;;
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Comment: К сожалению в Visual Studio данный пример не собирается с той же ошибкой.

Comment: Что делать? Бросайте писать в винде.

Comment: Это код для проекта под винду. Когда в линуксе появятся нормальные средства разработки, так сразу и брошу.

Comment: А мне emacs/make/bash/gcc/gdb как-то хватает

Comment: Написал, кстати, свой препроцессор https://github.com/mikelsv/opensource/tree/master/msvxcc.  Он был чудесным, логичным и все такое прочее, вплоть до момента #define A { . Но отдельный #ifdef MSVXCCTEMPLATE обрабатывает нормально и поставленную выше проблему решает. К сожалению пока валяется без дела, хотя есть идея восстановить на его основе кодогенератор и избавиться от шаблонов.